# Determine the convergence of sequence $\tan^2(1/n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to determine the convergence of sequence

$$ \sum^\infty_{n=1} \tan^2(1/n) $$

I have used the divergence test

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \tan^2(1/n) = \tan^2(0) = 0 $$

So we can't say if it diverge or not. I know i should use a comparison test but i don't know how to choose the other sequence to compare it with.

Comment: $$\tan(1/n)\sim \frac1n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\tan(x)
=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}
$.

For $0 \le x \le \pi/2$,
$\sin(x) \le x$.
Integrating this from
$0$ to $t$,
$\int_0^t \sin(x) dx
\le \int_0^t x dx
$
or
$-\cos(x)|_0^t
\le \frac{x^2}{2}|_0^t
$
or
$1-\cos(t) \le t^2/2$
or
$\cos(t)
\ge 1-t^2/2
$.

Therefore
$\tan(x)
\le \frac{x}{1-x^2/2}
$
so that, for $n \ge 1$,
$\tan(1/n)
\le \frac{1/n}{1-(1/n)^2/2}
< 2/n
$
so that
$\tan^2(1/n)
< 4/n^2
$
and the sum of these converges
by any test you want to use.

Answer (score 5):

$f(x)=\tan(x)$ is a non-negative convex function on the interval $[0,1]$, hence it follows that:
$$ 0\leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\tan^2\frac{1}{n}\leq\tan^2(1)\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq\frac{\pi^2\tan^2(1)}{6}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can use L'Hopital's rule to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} tan(1/n) / (1/n) = 1$. Then if you know that $\sum_n 1/n^p$ converges for $p > 1$, (in particular, $p = 2$),you are done.

Comment: $\tan x / x \to 1$ simply from the definition of the derivative. No need for l'H.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: If $f$ is defined in $[0,1], f(0) = 0,$ and $f'(0)$ exists, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f^2(1/n) <\infty.$ Proof: For small $x,$

$$\left |\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| = \left |\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right | \le |f'(0)| + 1.$$

Thus for large $n,$

$$|f(1/n)| \le (|f'(0)| + 1)/n \implies f^2(1/n) \le (|f'(0)| + 1)^2/n^2.$$

The series thus converges by comparison with $\sum 1/n^2.$